# Selenium image processing/removing of watermark

Tags: java, selenium, image-processing

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            WebElement anchoricon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[16]/ul[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/i[3]"));
            builder.moveToElement(anchoricon).moveByOffset(15,0).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0,5).release().perform();
```

I have coded the above in Selenium to automate a task whereby i have an anchor icon and it moves up by x:15 and then click and hold, and then slides down y:5 and eventually release the mouse click.

It is to simulate removal of watermark. However,when running the script, it runs and does not remove the watermark as expected. Can anyone help me on this?

P.S. I have changed x to 100 and y to 50, still no results.

[image: Highlighted is the anchoricon]

Highlighted is the anchoricon.